# How to get all data in JSON format from OpenCart 1.5.4 using vqmode and jQueryMobile

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, opencart, vqmod

I'm starting to make a mobile application to my shopping cart opencart 1.5.4 and would like to make all types of operations from the application, ie the customer to have all that I offer in OC, see Categories , the goods, create a new user account, log into the account, add to shopping cart, and finally to pay. but I want to make is native code in the app because I will use the phone functions.

for that reason I need to work around with web services, either nusoap or json (I prefer the latter since oc is designed for use).

I read in other questions OcJoy has a solution for this, but I do not know where to download or buy it.

however, would appreciate someone to give me a light with examples of how to do it.

In another post answered by OcJoy, says to list the products had to modify the code in catalog / controller / product / catalog.php, however, the file does not exist in my OC 1.5.4

I would greatly appreciate help with this situation.

Comment: i don't know about OcJoy but you can create a controller that will fetch all the data you need then display it in json format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rommel, do you have any example to do that in OC?

Comment: hi vhenriquez did you solve your problem? i developed a module which i think could help achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I would create a xml file with this code...

```
<modification>
<id><![CDATA[JSON infor for APP]]></id>
<version><![CDATA[0.8]]></version>
<vqmver><![CDATA[2.3]]></vqmver>
<author><![CDATA[Jeremy Fisk (jeremyfisk@clear.net.nz)]]></author>
<file name="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace" error="log"><![CDATA[$this->response->setOutput($this->render());]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[if(isset($this->request->get['json'])) {
            echo json_encode($this->data['products']);
            die;
        } else $this->response->setOutput($this->render()); ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

and then save it in the vqmod/xml folder... this means that if you navigate to http://example.com/index?route=product/category&path=26 it will show the page like normal, however if you add the json atribute to the url you will get the json data... the url for this would be http://example.com/index?route=product/category&path=26&json

This same code could be modified to add json data for the cart, for checkout, for product pages etc etc...

I trust this is off assistance to you and i look forward to hearing how you get on...

Regards

Jeremy

Comment: that looks great solution, but I am confuse with that why opencart not provide the APIs directly ? why need third part coder develop it again